# DataOutputStream different approach

Tags: java

I am using this code in a application for sending some string throw a socket.

```
public class OutgoingData {

public static DataOutputStream dos = null;
public static String toSend = "";
public static volatile boolean continuousSending = true;
public static String toSendTemp = "";

public static void startSending(final DataOutputStream d) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                dos = d;
                while (continuousSending) {

                    if (!toSend.equals(toSendTemp)) {
                        dos.writeUTF(toSend);
                        dos.flush();
                        toSendTemp = toSend;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();

}
```

And from another thread I am calling this method

```
    private void send(String str) {

    OutgoingData.toSend = str;
}
```

Are there any problems that could appear using this implementation? Excepting the case when send() is called synchronously from two threads.

I am not using something like this:

```
   private void send(final String str){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (OutgoingData.dos) {
                try {
                    OutgoingData.dos.writeUTF(str);
                    OutgoingData.dos.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();


}
```

Because the system on which this code is runned, has a limit on the number of threads a process can create and takes a long time to get a lock on an object.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is not thread safe:

```
if (!toSend.equals(toSendTemp)) {
    // toSend can be changed before this line happens
    // causing you to miss data
    dos.writeUTF(toSend);
    dos.flush();

    // or here
    toSendTemp = toSend;
}
```

You need some form of thread synchronization, regardless of whether or not it is "slow".

Comment: +1 As the `toSend` field is not volatile, you might not ever see this field change.

Comment: You are right i haven't encountered this problem, but in theory, this is more than likely to happen

Answer (score 1):

A better choice rather than busy waiting on a field is to use a `BlockingQueue<String>` This will ensure you never miss a value, nor do you consume CPU when there is nothing to do.

A good way of wrapping up a Queue and a Thread (pool) is to use an ExecutorService which does both.

In your case, a Socket stream is a queue already so queuing writing to another queue is likely to be redundant and all you really need to buffer your output stream.

> Because the system on which this code is runned, has a limit on the number of threads a process can create and takes a long time to get a lock on an object.

Creating a thread is more than 100x than creating a thread.  Ideally you don't want to have either. Note: the Socket already has a write lock.